# How to move all music from a certain playlist in Rhythmbox to my phone?

Tags: rhythmbox, samsung

I have a playlist of about 100 songs in rhythmbox and have my samsung's music folder open, how do I transition those songs into the phone without having to copy each one from its album and/or artist's folder?

I just don't want to have to pore through albums to try and find individual files when I've already compiled them into a single play list in rhythm box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all musics with the shortcut Ctrl+A and then just drag them in your phone, at the right location.